# Ubuntu 18.04 card SIM

Tags: 18.04

I have a HP ProBook 450 laptop Ubuntu 18.04.3. Kernel 5.4.6. I want to run LTE broadband internet however there is a problem the system can't see the device. Windows 7 is on the same laptop and the SIM card works. Please help.
MY equipment:
lsusb

1. Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b: 0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub Bus
   001 Device 006: ID 8087: 0a2a Intel Corp. Bus 001 Device 005: ID
   04f2: b51c Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Bus 001 Device 004: ID 276d:
   1160 Bus 001 Device 003: ID 090c: 1000 Silicon Motion, Inc. - Taiwan
   (formerly Feiya Technology Corp.) Flash Drive Bus 001 Device 002: ID
   03f0: 521d Hewlett-Packard Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b: 0002 Linux
   Foundation 2.0 root hub
2. lspci
   00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
   00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] (rev 07)
   00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
   00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
   00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
   00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
   00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
   00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
   00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
   00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
   00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
   00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
   00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
   01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
   02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 (rev 81)
   03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)

Comment: Where did the kernel come from?  That's not a standard Ubuntu kernel for 18.04 LTS (with or without HWE enabled), and it's not even the kernel used by my 20.04 box.  Have you tried Ubuntu kernels?

Comment: https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.4.6/

Comment: I installed myself from here:

Comment: Your detail is hard to read without line-breaks; it should be re-copied with formatting (use {} code tags).  Does it act the same with supported Ubuntu kernels instead of a *testing* kernel; and I've only seen bug reports so far on the kernel you have thus I wonder you should be taking it up there (launchpad, given the testing kernel).  5.3 is the latest 18.04 kernel (in proposed; not mainstream yet)  *If you have filed this as a bug (ie. why it sounds familiar), please provide lp bug report & I'll look as they contain more detail*